# If one cell contains ... Then count other cell if contains

Tags: excel, lookup, countif

I've got two columns and multiple rows. The columns contain the option `men`/`women` (`1`/`2`) and `Work` (`1`/`2`/`3`/`4`). I want to count how many men choose option `1`, how many choose option `2`, how many choose option `3` and how many choose option `4`. And then do the same for the women. But I cannot find any solution to it.

Could someone help me to find the correct formula?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Countif with multiple if requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043569/excel-countif-with-multiple-if-requirements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, you can do it using the countifs formula.

```
=COUNTIFS(D2:D101;1;AG2:AG101;1)
=COUNTIFS(D2:D101;2;AG2:AG101;1)
=COUNTIFS(D2:D101;3;AG2:AG101;1)
=COUNTIFS(D2:D101;4;AG2:AG101;1)

=COUNTIFS(D2:D101;1;AG2:AG101;2)
=COUNTIFS(D2:D101;2;AG2:AG101;2)
=COUNTIFS(D2:D101;3;AG2:AG101;2)
=COUNTIFS(D2:D101;4;AG2:AG101;2)
```